# how to connect to localhost with virtual domains via wifi?

Tags: apache, mobile, localhost, wifi

I have edited **"/etc/hosts"** where is added: 
**"27.0.0.1 my_page1.localhost"**, **"27.0.0.1 my_page2.localhost"** ...
Next I edited **"/etc/apache2/sites-available/default"** where is added: 
    **< VirtualHost *:80 >

DocumentRoot /var/www/my_page1

ServerName my_page1.localhost

< /VirtualHost >**
So I can run more sites on localhost with this command **"http://my_page1.localhost"**.
The problem is when I want to connect to localhost with mobile phone **192.168.2.5/my_page1.localhost** I receive **"Not Found. The requested URL /my_page1.localhost was not found on this server."**
How can I connect this localhost site via wifi? On Pc this works.

Answer (score 0):

Use only the ip and the port to connect to sites on your machine from a remote device. Set the servername to `SERVERNAME *` so it will respond to whatever host you request, reload apache and then connect to `192.168.2.5` on your phone.

For additional vhosts follow this example changing the port number:

```
Listen 8081
NameVirtualHost  *:8081
< VirtualHost *:8081 >
  DocumentRoot /var/www/my_page2
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias *
< /VirtualHost >
```

Reload apache and connect to it using `192.168.2.5:8081` on your mobile phone or `localhost:8081`.

The config above will direct your request to the correct app based on the port you access.

Comment: When I use "SERVERNAME * " cannot reload apache. "Invalid ServerName "*" use ServerAlias to set multiple server names." When use ServerAlias not work too.

Comment: Do you get any error when running configtest?  Could you inform that error?

Comment: configtest gives: "AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK"

Comment: Apache is reloading successfully. It just isn't sure where you want serve from, so it's choosing your localhost by default. To prevent this message from appearing, clarify that you want to serve from localhost by adding the lines I've added to my answer.

Comment: Edited answer works on PC "localhost:8081" but not on mobile "192.168.2.5:8081". I tried "192.168.2.5/localhost:8081" but not work too.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add `NameVirtualHost  *:8081` after `Listen 8081`. It makes a request from any ip on port 8081 to be matched against the virtual hosts.

Comment: Did not help. Works on Pc not on mobile